Implementing PowerQuery in VBA — Errors
I want to automate some PowerQuery data transformation so as to import it, at the click of a button, into a workbook in which I'm doing a whole lot of other stuff.
This is how I've gone about it... I:

imported a CSV file in PowerQuery
laid out all my transformations and gotten the result I wanted
copied out the resulting M code.
Then I:
went and opened a new workbook, started the macro recorder
fired up the PowerQuery editor
added a new blank query
changed the query's name to faithfully reflect my test query in the other workbook ("Contractuels", it's called)
pasted the previously copied M
pressed "Close and Load"
stopped the macro recorder, and copied out the result

What I got is this:
Sub ImportPQ()
    ExecuteExcel4Macro _
        "(""Contractuels"",""let" & Chr(10) & "  Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""/Users/ari/Nextcloud Nice/CMI/Contractuels.csv""), [Delimiter = "";"", Columns = 15, QuoteStyle = QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(10) & "  Headers = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars = true])," & Chr(10) & "  EstablishedColumnTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Headers, {{""Nom"", type text}, {""Prenom"", type text}, {""Nom" & _
        "_JF"", type text}, {""Date_naissance"", type date}, {""mail_ouvert"", type text}, {""Statut"", type text}, {""Entree_grade"", type date}, {""Echelon"", Int64.Type}, {""Date_echelon"", type date}, {""Rne"", type text}, {""EtabNom"", type text}, {""EtabBassin"", type text}, {""EtabVille"", type text}, {""nbre_heure"", type text}, {""Type_nomination"", type text}}, ""f" & _
        "r-FR"")," & Chr(10) & "  ChangedTypeNbHours = Table.TransformColumnTypes(EstablishedColumnTypes, {{""nbre_heure"", type number}})," & Chr(10) & "  NbContracts = Table.AddColumn(ChangedTypeNbHours, ""REP_SUP"", each if [Type_nomination] = ""REP"" or [Type_nomination] = ""SUP"" then 1 else 0, Int64.Type)," & Chr(10) & "  GroupedTable = Table.Group(NbContracts, {""Nom"", ""Prenom"", ""Nom_JF"", ""Date_naissanc" & _
        "e"", ""mail_ouvert"", ""Entree_grade"", ""Statut"", ""Echelon"", ""Date_echelon""}," & Chr(10) & "    {" & Chr(10) & "      {" & Chr(10) & "        ""Affectation""," & Chr(10) & "        each" & Chr(10) & "          let" & Chr(10) & "            SommeAffectations = List.Sum ([REP_SUP])" & Chr(10) & "          in" & Chr(10) & "            if SommeAffectations > 1 then ""Multiple"" else if SommeAffectations = 1 then ""Unique"" else ""Sans""," & Chr(10) & "        type text" & Chr(10) & "      }," & Chr(10) & "      {" & Chr(10) & " " & _
        "       ""Affectation_principale""," & Chr(10) & "        each" & Chr(10) & "          let" & Chr(10) & "            RepSup = Table.SelectRows (_, each [Type_nomination] = ""REP"" or [Type_nomination] = ""SUP"")," & Chr(10) & "            AffPrinc = Table.Max (RepSup, ""nbre_heure"")" & Chr(10) & "          in" & Chr(10) & "            AffPrinc" & Chr(10) & "      }" & Chr(10) & "    }" & Chr(10) & "  )," & Chr(10) & "  ExpandedAffPrinc = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(GroupedTable, ""Affectation_principale""," & _
        " {""Rne"", ""EtabNom"", ""EtabBassin"", ""EtabVille"", ""nbre_heure""}, {""Rne"", ""EtabNom"", ""EtabBassin"", ""EtabVille"", ""nbre_heure""})," & Chr(10) & "  DetectionCx = Table.AddColumn(ExpandedAffPrinc, ""Cx"", each if [Entree_grade] >= #date((if Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) >= #date (Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), 9, 1) then Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) else Date.Year(" & _
        "DateTime.LocalNow()) - 1), 7, 1) then ""C0"" else if [Entree_grade] < #date((if Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) >= #date (Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), 9, 1) then Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) else Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) - 1), 7, 1) and [Entree_grade] >= #date((if Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) >= #date (Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), 9, 1) then Date.Year" & _
        "(DateTime.LocalNow()) - 1 else Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) - 2), 7, 1) then ""C1"" else if (Duration.Days(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())-[Date_echelon]) / 365) > 5 and [Statut]<> ""CDI"" then ""CDIsable"" else """", type text)," & Chr(10) & "  ReorderCx = Table.ReorderColumns(DetectionCx, {""Nom"", ""Prenom"", ""Nom_JF"", ""Date_naissance"", ""mail_ouvert"", ""Entree_grade" & _
        """, ""Cx"", ""Statut"", ""Echelon"", ""Date_echelon"", ""Affectation"", ""Rne"", ""EtabNom"", ""EtabBassin"", ""EtabVille"", ""nbre_heure""})" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(10) & "  ReorderCx"")" & _
        ""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Contractuels;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Contractuels]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_ExternalData_1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub

And this is where everything went haywire: I got an error on ExecuteExcel4Macro, so I tried to modify the VBA code according to what I read here: How to automate a power query in VBA?
Private Sub ImportPQ()
    Dim qry As WorkbookQuery, qryTxt As String
    qryTxt = _
        "(""Contractuels"",""let" & Chr(10) & "  Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""/Users/ari/Nextcloud Nice/CMI/Contractuels.csv""), [Delimiter = "";"", Columns = 15, QuoteStyle = QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(10) & "  Headers = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars = true])," & Chr(10) & "  EstablishedColumnTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Headers, {{""Nom"", type text}, {""Prenom"", type text}, {""Nom" & _
        "_JF"", type text}, {""Date_naissance"", type date}, {""mail_ouvert"", type text}, {""Statut"", type text}, {""Entree_grade"", type date}, {""Echelon"", Int64.Type}, {""Date_echelon"", type date}, {""Rne"", type text}, {""EtabNom"", type text}, {""EtabBassin"", type text}, {""EtabVille"", type text}, {""nbre_heure"", type text}, {""Type_nomination"", type text}}, ""f" & _
        "r-FR"")," & Chr(10) & "  ChangedTypeNbHours = Table.TransformColumnTypes(EstablishedColumnTypes, {{""nbre_heure"", type number}})," & Chr(10) & "  NbContracts = Table.AddColumn(ChangedTypeNbHours, ""REP_SUP"", each if [Type_nomination] = ""REP"" or [Type_nomination] = ""SUP"" then 1 else 0, Int64.Type)," & Chr(10) & "  GroupedTable = Table.Group(NbContracts, {""Nom"", ""Prenom"", ""Nom_JF"", ""Date_naissanc" & _
        "e"", ""mail_ouvert"", ""Entree_grade"", ""Statut"", ""Echelon"", ""Date_echelon""}," & Chr(10) & "    {" & Chr(10) & "      {" & Chr(10) & "        ""Affectation""," & Chr(10) & "        each" & Chr(10) & "          let" & Chr(10) & "            SommeAffectations = List.Sum ([REP_SUP])" & Chr(10) & "          in" & Chr(10) & "            if SommeAffectations > 1 then ""Multiple"" else if SommeAffectations = 1 then ""Unique"" else ""Sans""," & Chr(10) & "        type text" & Chr(10) & "      }," & Chr(10) & "      {" & Chr(10) & " " & _
        "       ""Affectation_principale""," & Chr(10) & "        each" & Chr(10) & "          let" & Chr(10) & "            RepSup = Table.SelectRows (_, each [Type_nomination] = ""REP"" or [Type_nomination] = ""SUP"")," & Chr(10) & "            AffPrinc = Table.Max (RepSup, ""nbre_heure"")" & Chr(10) & "          in" & Chr(10) & "            AffPrinc" & Chr(10) & "      }" & Chr(10) & "    }" & Chr(10) & "  )," & Chr(10) & "  ExpandedAffPrinc = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(GroupedTable, ""Affectation_principale""," & _
        " {""Rne"", ""EtabNom"", ""EtabBassin"", ""EtabVille"", ""nbre_heure""}, {""Rne"", ""EtabNom"", ""EtabBassin"", ""EtabVille"", ""nbre_heure""})," & Chr(10) & "  DetectionCx = Table.AddColumn(ExpandedAffPrinc, ""Cx"", each if [Entree_grade] >= #date((if Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) >= #date (Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), 9, 1) then Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) else Date.Year(" & _
        "DateTime.LocalNow()) - 1), 7, 1) then ""C0"" else if [Entree_grade] < #date((if Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) >= #date (Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), 9, 1) then Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) else Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) - 1), 7, 1) and [Entree_grade] >= #date((if Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) >= #date (Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), 9, 1) then Date.Year" & _
        "(DateTime.LocalNow()) - 1 else Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) - 2), 7, 1) then ""C1"" else if (Duration.Days(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())-[Date_echelon]) / 365) > 5 and [Statut]<> ""CDI"" then ""CDIsable"" else """", type text)," & Chr(10) & "  ReorderCx = Table.ReorderColumns(DetectionCx, {""Nom"", ""Prenom"", ""Nom_JF"", ""Date_naissance"", ""mail_ouvert"", ""Entree_grade" & _
        """, ""Cx"", ""Statut"", ""Echelon"", ""Date_echelon"", ""Affectation"", ""Rne"", ""EtabNom"", ""EtabBassin"", ""EtabVille"", ""nbre_heure""})" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(10) & "  ReorderCx"")" & _
        ""
    For Each q In ThisWorkbook.Queries
        q.Delete
    Next q
    Set qry = ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add("Contractuels", qryTxt)
    Sheet3.Activate
    With Sheet3.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Contractuels;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Contractuels]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Contractuels"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub

Now, I get an error "The name 'Source' wasn't recognized. Make sure it is spelled correctly" (Run-time error 1004) (but I got other others before, which I haven't saved exactly [but there was something akin to Method .Refresh unrecognized about the last line of the script], and Excel crashed after several tries). Also, when I have a look at the 'Queries and Connections' window, there are queries piling up, and I cannot delete them, even manually (even though it seemed I requested the deletion of all queries in my VBA code)
As you can see, I am in way over my head... Any help will therefore be greatly appreciated!

Why in earth would you do it this way? Surely it’s simpler to have your PQ in the file and use VBA to refresh it rather than use VBA to create then refresh the query. The first option is a bit like using a hammer (VBA) to drive in a nail (PQ) whereas you’re trying to create a nail using a hammer then drive the nail in with the hammer

Your query text is wrong. It should just be:
qryTxt = _
    "let" & Chr(10) & "  Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""/Users/ari/Nextcloud Nice/CMI/Contractuels.csv""), [Delimiter = "";"", Columns = 15, QuoteStyle = QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(10) & "  Headers = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars = true])," & Chr(10) & "  EstablishedColumnTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Headers, {{""Nom"", type text}, {""Prenom"", type text}, {""Nom" & _
    "_JF"", type text}, {""Date_naissance"", type date}, {""mail_ouvert"", type text}, {""Statut"", type text}, {""Entree_grade"", type date}, {""Echelon"", Int64.Type}, {""Date_echelon"", type date}, {""Rne"", type text}, {""EtabNom"", type text}, {""EtabBassin"", type text}, {""EtabVille"", type text}, {""nbre_heure"", type text}, {""Type_nomination"", type text}}, ""f" & _
    "r-FR"")," & Chr(10) & "  ChangedTypeNbHours = Table.TransformColumnTypes(EstablishedColumnTypes, {{""nbre_heure"", type number}})," & Chr(10) & "  NbContracts = Table.AddColumn(ChangedTypeNbHours, ""REP_SUP"", each if [Type_nomination] = ""REP"" or [Type_nomination] = ""SUP"" then 1 else 0, Int64.Type)," & Chr(10) & "  GroupedTable = Table.Group(NbContracts, {""Nom"", ""Prenom"", ""Nom_JF"", ""Date_naissanc" & _
    "e"", ""mail_ouvert"", ""Entree_grade"", ""Statut"", ""Echelon"", ""Date_echelon""}," & Chr(10) & "    {" & Chr(10) & "      {" & Chr(10) & "        ""Affectation""," & Chr(10) & "        each" & Chr(10) & "          let" & Chr(10) & "            SommeAffectations = List.Sum ([REP_SUP])" & Chr(10) & "          in" & Chr(10) & "            if SommeAffectations > 1 then ""Multiple"" else if SommeAffectations = 1 then ""Unique"" else ""Sans""," & Chr(10) & "        type text" & Chr(10) & "      }," & Chr(10) & "      {" & Chr(10) & " " & _
    "       ""Affectation_principale""," & Chr(10) & "        each" & Chr(10) & "          let" & Chr(10) & "            RepSup = Table.SelectRows (_, each [Type_nomination] = ""REP"" or [Type_nomination] = ""SUP"")," & Chr(10) & "            AffPrinc = Table.Max (RepSup, ""nbre_heure"")" & Chr(10) & "          in" & Chr(10) & "            AffPrinc" & Chr(10) & "      }" & Chr(10) & "    }" & Chr(10) & "  )," & Chr(10) & "  ExpandedAffPrinc = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(GroupedTable, ""Affectation_principale""," & _
    " {""Rne"", ""EtabNom"", ""EtabBassin"", ""EtabVille"", ""nbre_heure""}, {""Rne"", ""EtabNom"", ""EtabBassin"", ""EtabVille"", ""nbre_heure""})," & Chr(10) & "  DetectionCx = Table.AddColumn(ExpandedAffPrinc, ""Cx"", each if [Entree_grade] >= #date((if Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) >= #date (Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), 9, 1) then Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) else Date.Year(" & _
    "DateTime.LocalNow()) - 1), 7, 1) then ""C0"" else if [Entree_grade] < #date((if Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) >= #date (Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), 9, 1) then Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) else Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) - 1), 7, 1) and [Entree_grade] >= #date((if Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) >= #date (Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), 9, 1) then Date.Year" & _
    "(DateTime.LocalNow()) - 1 else Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) - 2), 7, 1) then ""C1"" else if (Duration.Days(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())-[Date_echelon]) / 365) > 5 and [Statut]<> ""CDI"" then ""CDIsable"" else """", type text)," & Chr(10) & "  ReorderCx = Table.ReorderColumns(DetectionCx, {""Nom"", ""Prenom"", ""Nom_JF"", ""Date_naissance"", ""mail_ouvert"", ""Entree_grade" & _
    """, ""Cx"", ""Statut"", ""Echelon"", ""Date_echelon"", ""Affectation"", ""Rne"", ""EtabNom"", ""EtabBassin"", ""EtabVille"", ""nbre_heure""})" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(10) & "  ReorderCx"

